# Matrix representation of a homomorphism $\varphi: M_1\otimes M_2\to N_1\otimes N_2$.

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity.  Suppose $M_1, M_2, N_1, N_2$ are $R$-modules and $\varphi: M_1\otimes M_2 \to N_1\otimes N_2$ is a homomorphism.  How do you identify $\varphi$ with a 2x2 matrix $\begin{pmatrix} f_{11} & f_{12} \\ f_{21} & f_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ where $f_{ij}:M_i\to N_j$ is a homomorphism?  I initially thought that you would take for instance $f_{11}(m_1)=\pi_1(\varphi(m_1,0))=\pi_1(\varphi(m_1\otimes 0))$ (where $\pi_1$ is projection on the first coordinate) but then this is clearly bad because $\varphi(m_1\otimes 0) = 0$.  On the other hand it seems to me that you want

$$\begin{pmatrix} f_{11} & f_{12} \\ f_{21} & f_{22} \end{pmatrix} (m_1\otimes m_2) = \left([f_{11}(m_1)+f_{12}(m_2)] \otimes [f_{21}(m_1)+f_{22}(m_2)]\right) = \varphi(m_1\otimes m_2)$$

So you want the first coordinate of $\varphi(m_1\otimes m_2)$ to be $f_{11}(m_1) + f_{12}(m_2)$.  So in some sense it seems like you want $f_{11}(m_1)$ to be $\varphi$ restricted to $m_1$.

So my next thought was, well, tensors are basically trying to define a notion of multiplication between module elements.  So maybe what I want is $f_{11}(m_1) = \pi_1(\varphi(m_1,1))$.  But it seems possible that there isn't even a unitary element in $M_2$.

I get the sense that I just profoundly misunderstand ... everything.

Comment: I don't think that you can identify $\varphi$ with an only matrix. Think about the case where are all $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think that maybe you are confusing the tensor product $\otimes$ with the direct sum/biproduct operation $\oplus$. When $\varphi \colon M_1 \oplus M_2 \rightarrow N_1 \oplus N_2$ is a homomorphism, you can use the natural inclusions $M_i \rightarrow M_1 \oplus M_2$ and projections $N_1 \oplus N_2 \rightarrow N_i$ to decompose $\varphi$ into four homomorphisms $f_{ij}$. However, for the tensor product $\otimes$ there is neither a natural inclusion $M_i \rightarrow M_1 \otimes M_2$ nor a projection $N_1 \otimes N_2 \rightarrow N_i$.

Comment: @levap I think you're right!  Thank you!